# OSX El Capitan freezes after connecting to SMB share

Tags: mac, macos, performance, smb

Why does OS X El Capitan freeze after it connects to an SMB share? The OS will successfully connect to the remote SMB share and mount it.  After a short time passes, the Finder freezes and the entire OS follows.  What should I do?

Comment: I am using El Capitan and regularly connect to SMB shares successfully. I would suggest it's an issue with either the connection itself or the contents of the share.

Do you have another SMB share to which you can try and connect, to test whether it works, or doesn't work, consistently?

Comment: Do you mean, another host or another shared folder inside the same host?

Comment: I would try both if you can, and see if it exhibits the same behavior. If it does, it's a system problem. If it doesn't, it's an issue with that particular share and it's contents.